# How to add column in order list Opencart?

Tags: php, html, dashboard, opencart2.x

How to add column in this table of opencart in the admin dashboard?
Because I want to insert the 'company name' in the middle of 'Customer' and 'Status'?

What file should I edit to make it done?

[image: order list]

Comment: Might be beneficial to post this on the OpenCart support forums, there might be a similar question. There will be a template and a corresponding PHP file in the admin folder within your OpenCart files, you might have to poke around a bit. I don't know specifically because I can't look at mine at the moment.

Comment: hey thanks! I add a 'Company name' td in the order_list.tpl and add this as it content `<td class="right"><?php echo $order['comapany_name']; ?></td>` but it giving me an error...I am guessing I need to add something else to the model or controller files, but I am a bit unsure what...do you have an idea?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Undefined index: company_name in E:\wamp\www\xxxadmin\view\template\sale\order_list.tpl on line 148

Comment: Okay I think in admin>controller>sale>order.php you will find around line 383 where you might need to add the company name field (possibly)  'company' => $result['company_name']. No guarantee this will work there might be other things you need to add, haven't been able to test it out.

Comment: But, 'company_name' may not exist, it might be 'entry_company' or something along those lines.

Comment: I add something like this under `function getList()`  and still the same error nothing change `if (isset($this->request->get['company_name'])) {
   $company_name = $this->request->get['company_name'];
  } else {
   $company_name = null;
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87127/discussion-between-winresh24-and-lizzeiy).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to add a column to a list view in OpenCart, you need to...

- Add a language definition for each relevant language ("column_xyz")
- Make sure the column is selected in the SQL Query, which you can find in the Model layer
- Re-map the database-column to a view-column in the controller function
- Show the title and values in the HTML table
- Implement sorting and filtering, which will have more effects on your view, controller and model.

This is just a quick checklist I use for planning. Each step is more complex than one sentence can explain. You should absolutely check the OpenCart Community Forum for more detailed manuals. One example I found would be [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=48060), they want to show a different column but the principles are the same.